# How to display pictures / photos in Mapbox?

Tags: photos

I have a [website](http://www.radfahren-berlin.de) for better cycling in Berlin [www.radfahren-berlin.de](http://www.radfahren-berlin.de). there is imported official data and added custom data (how wide is the cycling lane,..). I want to diplay the actual photographs of the various cycling sections and I am neaer desperation: How to do this? What are possible ways (in the end clickable or showing up on hoover)

Section with properties are

```
{
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "CC": "ja",
    "sorvt_typ": "Geh-/Radweg, baulich unterschieden",
    "Oberfläche": 2,
    "Schutz": "",
    "Breite": 130,
    "stor_name": "Pankow",
    "Planungsstand": "",
    "rva_typ": "Radwege",
    "sobj_kz": "03-001592",
    "segm_bez": "B96a",
    "stst_str": "Breite Straße",
    "Farbe": "",
    "ortstl": "Pankow",
    "laenge": 55,
    "fertig": "",
    "b_pflicht": "ja",
    "segm_segm": "46600011_46600027.01"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "coordinates": [
      [13.402111, 52.569315],
      [13.401811, 52.569304],
      [13.401674, 52.5693],
      [13.401555, 52.56931],
      [13.401405, 52.56934],
      [13.401339, 52.56938]
    ],
    "type": "LineString"
  }
}
```